# Set the Rstudio files pane directory from the R console?

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there any interaction from R to RStudio possible?

I would really like, for example, to set the RStudio files pane directory from the R console, like `setFilesPane(getwd())` or such. I haven't found anything though.

**Edit: To clarify:** In RStudio there is a "files pane" (bottom right)

[image]

This can be navigated like any file explorer. However I would like to set the files pane directory (the directory whose contents are shown in the files pane) from my R code instead of having to navigate to my project folder by hand every time. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I tried to clarify...

Comment: AFAIK, the files pane shows the contents of the current working directory (check it by running `getwd()` or change it using `setwd(...)`). Also, check what happens when you first navigate to any random folder in the files pane and then click the arrow at the top of the console pane (bottom left).

Comment: @docendodiscimus the files pane does not update with `setwd`.

Comment: @Laterow, it does, when you (1) use `setwd("some/path")` and then (2) click the arrow in the console pane.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes, true, the arrow works.

Comment: Have you tried using **Project**s? When you open a Project in RStudio the "file pane" is set to the root-directory of your Project. Have a look at https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects

Comment: @docendodiscimus I would like to know if there is a way without using a mouse.

Comment: Ha! Thanks @docendodiscimus that arrow does exactly what I needed. Funny how I never clicked it in the last 3 years or so :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rstudioapi::filesPaneNavigate()` ought to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Was answered by @docendodiscimus:

> click the arrow at the top of the console pane (bottom left)
>   Thanks!

Comment: such a simple solution!